# Python - How do a make a script available in every directory?

Tags: python

I have a script which is kind of used as a title for most of my python projects, and I have it as its own separate file. How do I make this globally available, without having to copy and paste it everywhere?

Comment: Put it someplace in `sys.path` and import it.

Comment: Put it on internet as a file probably github